# Rack Console Setup

Tags: rackmount, keyboard-video-mouse

I rack console with mouse, keyboard and monitor. It's only output port is a vga connection. My KVM switch has USB Mouse, USB Keyboard, PS2 Keyboard, PS2 Mouse and VGA. The cables I bought have VGA on one end and VGA and 1 USB on the other. The keyboard and mouse for the console don't work. Any ideas? Do I need a different cable that has two USB ports? Different KVM switch?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a custom cable designed to work with a VGA port that has an integrated USB port on the same connector.  Unless your KVM is designed with that in mind (I would imagine the documentation would not only say it, but would provide information on how to get the specific cables) I would suspect that you need to use standard cables (on standard ports).